# Replace multiple items in string using cases/switch in PHP

Tags: php, string, switch-statement

I'm trying to do something where I take a long string from a database, and replace possible tags like [timeYEAR] [timeMONTH] [timeDAY] - Basically anything within [] and then based on cases or a switch replace that item with something else.

Like replace [timeYEAR] with 2013.

But I do not want to create a  function for each possible case.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you replacing the tags with? Where is that value coming from?

Comment: Use `str_replace()`. You can give it arrays of original and replacement strings, and it will do them all in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish something like this with [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) if you want to do something more dynamic (case insensitive matching, allowing multiple spaces between `time` and `{time_unit}`, etc).

```
<?php
$res = preg_replace_callback('/\[time(?P<type>[^\]]+)\]/ui', function ($matches) {
    switch (trim(strtolower($matches['type']))) {
        case 'year':
            return date('Y');
            break;
        case 'month':
            return date('F');
            break;
        case 'day':
            return date('j');
            break;
        default:
            return $matches[0];
            break;
    }
}, '[timemonth] [timeday], [timeyear] [timenope]');
```

If it doesn't need to be more dynamice, [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) is probably a bit quicker.

```
<?php
$res = strtr('[timeMONTH] [timeDAY], [timeYEAR]', array(
    '[timeMONTH]'  => date('F'),
    '[timeDAY]'    => date('j'),
    '[timeYEAR]'   => date('Y'),
));
```

Replace the `date` calls with whatever your source for the values happens to be.

Comment: Thank You! Exactly what I'm looking for. I just removed the time from '/\[time(?P<type>[^\]]+)\]/ui' to '/\[(?P<type>[^\]]+)\]/ui' so I could use none time related keys. Do you think that will be ok?

Comment: Hey I have another question regarding this. What if I want to pass some data (variable) with the tag? [tagName:variableInfo]  -- Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, but you'd *have* to use `preg_replace_callback`. Then just split the `$matches['type']` string by colons `explode(':', $matches['type'])` and do what you need to do. That's a bit simplistic, but you get the idea. You just need to matching anything that's contained in square brackets, which the above does. Do any further processing you need inside the callback function.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy- But how would the call back detect the tag because the variable changes the tag. Like one could be [tagName:variable1] and another could be [tagName:variable2]

Comment: `$parts = explode($matches['type']); $tag_name = array_shift($parts);` Then use the rest of `$parts` however you like.